# Comparison of pacts over other tools

Tags: pact

I've been doing some analysis to mock the dependent services while running the integration service in the dev sandbox machine. Thats when I came to know about pact - a contract testing tool. The consumer testing can be used to mock the services. Before deciding the pact tool, would like to know other alternatives similar to the pact.

If anyone prepared such comparison matrix with other tools in the past, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find a list of comparisons between Pact and other tools on the Pact docs page https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/comparisons